# Desplazamiento de columnas a la izquierda en una matriz

Tags: c#

estoy atorado en un problema, tengo una matriz y quiero que la primera fila quede igual pero a partir de la segunda fila se recorra un valor a la izquierda,

> Matriz original
>
> ```
> {{"d4","e0","b8","1e"},
>  {"27","bf","b4","41"},
>  {"11","98","5d","52"},
>  {"ae","f1","e5","30"}}; 
>
> Desplazamiento a la izquierda 
>
>  {{"d4","e0", "b8", "1e"},
>  {"bf", "b4", "41", "27"}, 
>  {"5d", "52", "11", "98"},
>  {"30", "ae", "f1", "e5"}};
> ```
>
> como se muestra la matriz original y luego es como se debe ver con el desplazamiento de un valor a la izquierda

>

> ```
> public static string[,] clave = new string[4, 4]{{"d4","e0","b8","1e"},
>                                                       {"27","bf","b4","41"},
>                                                       {"11","98","5d","52"},
>                                                       {"ae","f1","e5","30"}};
>
>     public static Int32[,] w = new Int32[4, 4];
>    // Int32 aux;
>     public Form1()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
>
>     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>         int f, c=0;
>         int x=-1, y;
>
>         string cad;
>         for (f = 0; f < 4; f++)
>         {
>             x++;
>             for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
>             {
>
>                 w[f, c] = Int32.Parse(clave[f, x], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
>             }
>
>             x = x << 0;
>
>         }
> ```

este es mi código pero solo me imprime los valores que están en diagonal y no me hace el desplazamiento a la izquierda

Comment: Una duda...que pretendes hacer en esta línea?  `x = x << 0;`

Comment: No veo que a partir de la segunda fila se desplacen los valores a la izquierda. La segunda fila si parece desplazada 1 a la izquierda, pero la tercera parece estar desplazada 2 y la cuarta parece estar desplazada 3 ¿es eso correcto?

Comment: Quiere el resultado ser un matriz de _string_ (como el ejemplo arriba) o un matriz de _Int32_ (como `w`)?

Answer (score 1):

El patron es como asi:
En matriz `w` fila **0** columna `c`, cada elemento toma el valor de `clave` en la misma fila en columna `c`+**0**
En matriz `w` fila **1** columna `c`, cada elemento toma el valor de `clave` en la misma fila en columna `c`+**1**
En matriz `w` fila **2** columna `c`, cada elemento toma el valor de `clave` en la misma fila en columna `c`+**2**
En matriz `w` fila **3** columna `c`, cada elemento toma el valor de `clave` en la misma fila en columna `c`+**3**

El problema aqui es el resultado de `c + numero_de_fila` puede exceder 4, el maximo largo de la fila.
Y para evitar *IndexOutOfBound* error, realizamos modulo (`%`) 4, asi el resultado esta entre 0 y 3 (inclusivos).
En esta manera, podemos lograr el desplazamiento a la izquierda de acuerdo con la regla descrito.

**Por ejemplo:**

El valor de `w[2,0]` debe ser el valor de `clave` fila 2 y de columna: `(0+2) % 4`, resulta a `2`.
Asi, `w[2,0]` toma el valor de `clave[2,2]` (*5d*).

El valor de `w[3,1]` debe ser el valor de `clave` fila 3 y de columna: `(1+3) % 4`, resulta a `0`.
Asi, `w[3,1]` toma el valor de `clave[3,0]` (*ae*).

**El codigo:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int desplazar = 0;
    int columnaClave = 0;

    for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++)
    {
        desplazar = f;

        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
        {
            columnaClave = (c + desplazar) % 4;
            w[f, c] = Int32.Parse(clave[f, columnaClave], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        }
    }
}
```